# PHP need to display MPTT without modifying MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, mptt

I have a MPTT organized MySql database which i need to display , there is no level limit  and i can't alter the database, i've tryed http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/, but still got me a few headeachs.

Comment: It would help if you told what those headaches are about.

Comment: That mysql like is an excellent explanation of MPTT. Are you having trouble implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen [open sourced Baum package](https://github.com/decebal/baum) to solve this one, has most of the nested algorithms implemented and although it can be improved it was the best starting point I found around.